# reseting a flow layout with a button

Tags: java, jbutton

What I am trying to do here is set the layout scheme once I press a button to align all the buttons to the left of the contentPane I have three buttons this is the code i have for that particular button

```
  leftButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   cp.setLayout( new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

  }
 } );
```

it also compiles just find but dont align anything to the left. Must I add more to this code or should this do it?

Comment: do I need to add all the code for someone to help me

Comment: Well, you're just creating a new layout...without anything in it, I think you would need to re-enter all your buttons on your Form

Answer (score 1):

After you have set the new LayoutManager, you need to call revalidate() on the container. So from your code, something like the following should work.

```
leftButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        cp.setLayout( new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        cp.revalidate();
    }
} );
```